# MySQL query to count a word appearance provides unstable result

Tags: mysql, sql, select, replace

Here is my table create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here is some example data:

```
id, value
-----------------------------
'1', '__cccccccc; Myword'
'2', '__ddddddd; Myword'
'3', 'OOO; myword; anotherword'
```

This is my query which aims to count the number of times the following string (including semicolon and space at the beginning): `; myword` appeared in a record:

```
select `mytable`.`value`, length(`mytable`.`value`) as 'string length', length(replace(`mytable`.`value`,'; myword','')) as 'after replace', 
(length(replace(`mytable`.`value`,'; myword',''))-length(`mytable`.`value`)) as 'after sub', 
(length(replace(`mytable`.`value`,'; myword',''))-length(`mytable`.`value`))/8 as 'after divide'
from `test`.`mytable`
where LOWER(`mytable`.`value`) like ('%; myword%') OR LOWER(`mytable`.`value`) like ('%; myword');
```

The result I get:

```
'__cccccccc; Myword', '18', '18', '0', '0.0000'
'__ddddddd; Myword', '17', '17', '0', '0.0000'
'OOO; myword; anotherword', '24', '16', '-8', '-1.0000'
```

the first problem, as the results show, in the first and second records, the word `myword` is not found, but it actually exists. Why isn't it counted?

The secondand problem, in the last record, the result is in minus. Why? I subtract 16-24 which should be 8.

Comment: `replace` is case-sensitive, which explains the first problem, and the second problem occurs because you have the terms in the wrong order; you are calculating 16-24, not 24-16. To solve the first problem you could use `regexp_replace` instead (if you are using MySQL 8.0 +), and to solve the second problem just change the order of the terms.

Comment: @jpw Thanks. But what should I do  if the word I am searching is case insensitive? I am dealing with exisiting data that I can not manually change.

Comment: use `BINARY` keyword

Comment: @James Or, I can use `REPLACE(LOWER(value), '; myword', '')` ?? It wil always lower the case and compare it with the lower case keyword? Isn't it?

Comment: but what happens if you receive upper case as input?

Comment: Which input? upper case will always be converted to lower case using LOWER(). Then conduct the replacement. So I always use Replace with lowecase. As for the keyword, we also always use lower case.